# What is the proper typing when using refPath with mongoose?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, typescript, express, mongoose

Typescript throws
"Type 'Vote' does not satisfy the constraint 'Document'.
  Types of property 'on' are incompatible.
    Type 'ObjectId' is not assignable to type '(event: string | symbol, listener: (...args: any[]) => void) => Vote'.
      Type 'ObjectId' provides no match for the signature '(event: string | symbol, listener: (...args: any[]) => void): Vote'."

when I'm using refPath.

```js
import { Document, Schema } from 'mongoose';
interface Vote extends Document {
  user: Schema.Types.ObjectId;
  onModel: string;
  on: Schema.Types.ObjectId;
}
export default Vote;



import mongoose, { Schema } from 'mongoose';
import Vote from '../types/Vote';
const VoteSchema: Schema = new Schema({
  user: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
  on: {
    type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    required: true,
    refPath: 'onModel',
  },
  onModel: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
    enum: ['Post', 'Comment'],
  },
});
export default mongoose.model<Vote>('Vote', VoteSchema);
```

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT :**

It would seem that I misunderstood what was wrong, and didn't test my answer. Also at the time, I did not understand what he was trying to do with the `Document`, but nothing was wrong with that either.

What was actually wrong was the fact that the property `on`, [contrary to what the docs say](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html#dynamic-ref), is protected and can not be used as a schema pathname.

Changing `on` to `property`, or almost any other key, solves the issue in question. Quite the unfortunate choice of property key in the docs...

Working version of the original question

```
import mongoose, { Schema, Document } from 'mongoose';

interface Vote extends Document {
    user: Schema.Types.ObjectId;
    propertyModel: string;
    property: Schema.Types.ObjectId;
}

const VoteSchema: Schema = new Schema({
    user: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    property: {
        type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        required: true,
        refPath: 'propertyModel',
    },
    propertyModel: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
        enum: ['Post', 'Comment'],
    },
});

const Vote = mongoose.model<Vote>('Vote', VoteSchema);

(async () => {
    await mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/test', {
        useNewUrlParser: true,
        useUnifiedTopology: true,
    });

    const vote = await Vote.create({
        user: '5f3bb78267ad4152b4079344',
        property: '5f3bb8468e770d52a4bc91f5',
        propertyModel: 'Comment',
    });

    await vote.save();
    await mongoose.disconnect();
})();
```

---

<strike>The problem is not with `refPath`, but that you are extending `Document` and not fulfilling some requirements.
More specifically: it's complaining that it can't find an `ObjectId` property, which it shouldn't, because this is a schema and not a document.</strike>

Honestly, I don't know why you are mixing `Document` and `Schema`. Try this.

```
import mongoose, { Schema } from 'mongoose';
import Vote from '../types/Vote';
const VoteSchema: Schema = new Schema({
    user: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    on: {
        type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        required: true,
        refPath: 'onModel',
    },
    onModel: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
        enum: ['Post', 'Comment'],
    },
});
export default mongoose.model('Vote', VoteSchema);
```

Comment: May I know, at the time of writing this, did you test whether this code works? Because as of today when I tried the above codes. (1) using 'on' will return error. (2) it will complain cannot find onModal

Comment: I'll be honest: I did not. I worked from the docs of refPath which seems to say that using `on` is fine. That was obviously not the case, and I have updated the answer with a working example. Thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: I've been working around ref path for past 2 weeks and your updates reflects what I've been using as well. Thanks for the update.